# QR Code Windows 10 UWP IOT (Raspberry pi 2)

Tags: c#, qr-code, uwp, raspberry-pi2, iot

I am pretty new to the IOT and UWP for windows 10.
Is it possible to read QR Code using windows 10 IOT? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
[ZXing.NET](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/) library.

ZXing.Net has a Windows Runtime Component that works in Windows 8.1 apps. It loads in a Windows 10 app too using the  WinRT .dll.

Also, You can get it from nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net

I'm adding a blog post that demos a simple Windows Phone 8 app for performing QR code scanning using ZXing.Net.Mobile

[QR scanning using ZXing.Net mobile demo](http://www.davidbritch.com/2014/07/qr-code-scanning-in-windows-phone-app.html)

I hope that supports your question.